watchOS timer app freezes UI in dimmed state while haptics continue working
I'm working on a watchOS timer app that needs to run for 3 1/2 minutes while showing countdown numbers. I think that I've discovered that there's nothing to do with the watch dimming- that's a system setting that the watch wearer sets for 15 or 70 seconds. But the face can update while dimmed--I see that in the native timer app for example. This is a tricky one to debug, as when the physical watch is attached to Xcode as a device, it doesn't dim or freeze the face at all. It's only when I restart the app on the physical watch that I see the issues, and there are 2:

With the first dimming, it skips a number. The timing is fine, it's just that the number that would show when the watch dims does not. This is not mission-critical, but it is annoying.
After about 2 1/2 minutes of running, the UI completely freezes but the haptic feedback continues working correctly. When the watch is tapped, the display updates to the correct number. This is a bug that I'd like to fix.

This is what I've tried so far:

Standard Timer with WKExtendedRuntimeSession
DispatchSourceTimer with various intervals
Separate timers for UI updates and core logic
Different UI refresh mechanisms using DispatchQueue
Various combinations of forcing UI updates using objectWillChange.send()

Here's my current code using DispatchSourceTimer and WKExtendedRuntimeSession:
class TimerManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var phase: ExercisePhase = .notStarted
    @Published var currentSet = 1
    @Published var isSqueezing = true
    @Published var secondsRemaining = 10
    @Published var isPaused = false
    
    private var runtimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession?
    private var timerSource: DispatchSourceTimer?
    private var uiRefreshWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    
    func scheduleNextUpdate() {
        guard !isPaused && phase != .completed && phase != .notStarted else { return }
        
        stopSession()
        
        // Start new session
        runtimeSession = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
        runtimeSession?.start()
        
        // Create main timer for exercise logic
        let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
        timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(1))
        timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
            self?.updateExercise()
        }
        
        // Create UI refresh mechanism
        scheduleUIRefresh()
        
        timerSource = timer
        timer.resume()
    }
    
    private func scheduleUIRefresh() {
        uiRefreshWorkItem?.cancel()
        
        let workItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            
            if !self.isPaused && self.phase != .completed {
                self.scheduleUIRefresh()
            }
        }
        
        uiRefreshWorkItem = workItem
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: workItem)
    }
}

The app uses watchOS's Physical Therapy session type. The core timing functionality (including haptics) works perfectly, but the UI updates are frozen in the dimmed state at the times that I described.
I've also tried:
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true)

and
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)

But the same problems persist.
Has anyone encountered similar problems with watchOS UI updates in a dimmed state but with the code happily running in the background?
I'm coding in Xcode 16.2 and Swift 6.0.3 and testing on a physical Apple Watch Series 8 with watchOS 11. Any emulator I try works fine. Thanks super in advance if you can weigh in.
